# Shell script to logout a user from unix

Tags: bash, unix

I need some guidance regarding this question. I want to write a shell script which will immediately log out the user (except root user) as soon as the user logs in to the system (should work on any unix variant). I am wondering whether this is possible or not?

My approach would be something like this condition:

```
If [[ $(id) != root]]  then 
    logout 
else 
    login
```

But i am not sure how to script this and in which initialization file to put the script (maybe .profile?).

Answer (score 4):

Simply set to all users the shell /bin/false

That closes every shell after a successful login. To set that shell you can use this command:

```
usermod -s /bin/false someuser
```

Comment: Can you tell the difference between an unsuccessful login and a "successful" login where the shell is `/bin/false`?

Comment: Also, many systems have a `/bin/nologin` as a registered shell. It's better than `/bin/false` because you can use it to provide a customized message to people who try to log in.

Comment: With the parmeter -l you can also disabled the login as an alternative. I never used that nologin shell so I have no experience with that one, but I guess it should do its work too.

Answer (score 0):

Why kicking out the user at all?
I do not see the advantage of letting a user in and kick him afterwards out

1) Delete the user's account.

2) as rekire said: disallow login

3) use a random password `passwd -l` sets the password to a random one (is effectively the same as 2)

Comment: `passwd -l` will not lock the password on OS X (OP requested that the answer work on any UNIX variant).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question:

for `bash`

```
(( $(id -u) > 0 )) && echo 'do something if NOT ROOT (eg. exit)'
```

or for sh

```
[ `whoami` == "root" ] || echo 'do something if NOT ROOT (eg. exit)'
```

Comment: Thanks jm666..just one question- where to place this script so that it automatically gets trigger once the user login to the shell..